# Discord Bot random prompt from array, no repeats

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

This is the problem I'm having. This is meant to choose a word at random from the array when a user calls !prompt, but then it'll only spit out that prompt and nothing else. It's supposed to pick randomly every time !prompt is called. How do I fix it?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client();

const PREFIX = '!';


const token = 'notforstackoverflow';
bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})



var prompts = ["Cloud", "Tifa", "Sarge", "Chocobo",
"Sephiroth",
"Materia",
"Lifestream",
"Mako",
"Ancient",
"Cetra", 
"Lost number",
"Ultimate weapon",
"Point of no return",
"Eorzea cafe",
"Artnia",
"Healing Spring",
"Unseen Realm",
"Sarnoia civil war",
"Dimensional shift",
"Day of conjuction",
"Disguise",
"Pirate",
"Monster",
"Astos",
"Four Fiends",
"Matoya",
"Sarah",
"Dancing Girl",
"Honey Bee",
"Rydia",
"Tidus",
"Tuna",
"Rikku",
"Aerith",
"Jenova",
"Jessie",
"Vincent Valentine",
"Zack Fair",
"Butch",
"Kotch",
"Weapons",
"Nibelheim",
"SOLDIER"];
const randomPrompt = prompts[Math.floor(Math.random() * prompts.length)];

bot.on('message', message=>{
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    switch(args[0]){
case 'prompt':
message.channel.send(randomPrompt); 
break;  }
})



bot.login(token);
```

An example of what's going on, say the user calls !prompt and it spits out "Sephiroth". It will then ONLY spit out "Sephiroth" and nothing else until the bot is reset.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `randomPrompt` as a `const` one time when the script is initialized, and referring back to the same `const` each time. Instead, decide what the `randomPrompt` value will be when your message handler is executed:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client();

const PREFIX = '!';


const token = 'notforstackoverflow';
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})



var prompts = ["Cloud", "Tifa", "Sarge", "Chocobo",
    "Sephiroth",
    "Materia",
    "Lifestream",
    "Mako",
    "Ancient",
    "Cetra",
    "Lost number",
    "Ultimate weapon",
    "Point of no return",
    "Eorzea cafe",
    "Artnia",
    "Healing Spring",
    "Unseen Realm",
    "Sarnoia civil war",
    "Dimensional shift",
    "Day of conjuction",
    "Disguise",
    "Pirate",
    "Monster",
    "Astos",
    "Four Fiends",
    "Matoya",
    "Sarah",
    "Dancing Girl",
    "Honey Bee",
    "Rydia",
    "Tidus",
    "Tuna",
    "Rikku",
    "Aerith",
    "Jenova",
    "Jessie",
    "Vincent Valentine",
    "Zack Fair",
    "Butch",
    "Kotch",
    "Weapons",
    "Nibelheim",
    "SOLDIER"
];

bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'prompt':
            const randomPrompt = prompts[Math.floor(Math.random() * prompts.length)];
            message.channel.send(randomPrompt);
            break;
    }
})

bot.login(token);
```

<sub>I've indented your code in accordance with generally accepted indentation standards for JavaScript. Your original code might be a bit more human-readable if it were indented correctly; you should consider using a proper IDE that will help you with this.</sub>